# Finding partition of a relation such that each element in partition set is a cartesian product

Tags: relations, cross-product, set-partition

Suppose we have sets 
A = {A<sub>1</sub>,A<sub>2</sub>.... A<sub>n</sub>} and B = {B<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>,...B<sub>m</sub>}

and a relation R having elements like (A<sub>i</sub>,B<sub>j</sub>).

The aim is to make a partition set P of relation R such that each element (or cover of the partition) in the partition set is a cartesian product.

Example:

If R = {{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>},{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>}}

then I want to make a partition set like

P = { { {A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>} }, { {A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>} } }

Here both { {A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>} } and {{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>}} are cartesian products or we may say set of elements from A and B such that all elements Ai are matched with Bj in that set.

The union of these two sets make R and also { {A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>} } and {{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>}} are disjoint hence making P the partition set.

What algorithm/theorem should I follow to find a partition set like this?
Note that R here will be a relation where always consisting of pairs as it's elements in which always first item will be from A and second from B.
So 
{B<sub>1</sub>,A<sub>1</sub>} is not possible.

Other examples:

R = {{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>}}
then P = {{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>}}
because both {A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>} and {A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>} are independently cross products.

R = {{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>},{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>},{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>3</sub>}}

then P contains elements {{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>},{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>},{A<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>}} and {{A<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>3</sub>}}

Comment: "Example: if $R = \ldots$" You shouldn't mix up brackets and curly brackets, unless you assume that your relation has to be symmetric.

Comment: Oops.. will follow the braces only.

Comment: Such a partition will always exist if you allow for cartesian products of cardinality $1$, but for instance the equality relation on $A=B=\{1,2\}$ is an example where you can't do better.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve it, so it depends what you are aiming at. For instance to minimize the number of parts of the decomposition?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek yes.. in fact maybe there can be many partitions of such kind. 

Is the aim to minimize the number of parts of the decomposition?
Yes

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier I have to allow cartesian product of cardinality 1 as well as per the requirement. I have to find the best partition sets out of many possible ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bipartite graph $G$ (with $A$ on one side and $B$ on the other, with edges determined by $R$). Then what you are asking for is known under the name *biclique partition* of $G$. You will find some literature about it online.

The problem of finding the smallest such partition (minimum cardinality biclique partition) is NP-hard, and I think it remains NP-hard in the class of  bipartite graphs.

Comment: Thanks @Michal Adamaszek for your help.
I found papers related to this topic.